# What determines the user that triggers "respository_dispatch" in github actions

Tags: github, repository, github-actions

I have 2 repos: repoA and repoB.
RepoA sends a HTTP request to RepoB to trigger a workflow via repository_dispatch action.

I am userA and it is my event that triggered RepoA's workflow. However, when the workflow is triggered in RepoB it is triggered by a userB. I am part of the org that owns the repos and am the owner of both. My actions are the last actions in both repos.

I can't figure out why the other user would be the "triggered by" user for the GitHub action.
I am doing some testing and will need to be the one to receive the failure emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in the action's github repo. For those curious, the user account associated with the token used will always be the triggering account.

Github handle: peter-evans:

"The actor of the repository_dispatch workflow will always be the user account associated with the token you are using. Instead of using your own account to create the token, what I would suggest is to make a new GitHub account as a "machine account." Make sure the account has access to the target repositories and create the repo scoped token for use with this action. Additionally, set an email address for the machine account that acts as an email group. So emails to that address will be delivered to all members of your team. Then when the CI run fails, your whole team should be notified."

https://github.com/peter-evans/repository-dispatch/issues/40